# We have 11 people and 6 box seats at the super bowl. The number of ways we can choose 6 people from the 11 to sit in those 6 box seats.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Homework. Does not matter which particular box seat they are in.

Comment: choose is your key word...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a bag of $n$ balls and we want to choose $k$ of them where order does not matter.

There are a total of $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ balls in a line. Since the order does not matter for the chosen $k$ balls we need to account for those arrangements. Similarly, the order does not matter for the other $(n-k)$ balls.

Hence we get

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> We have 11 people and 6 box seats at the super bowl. The number of ways we can **choose 6** people from the **11** to sit in those 6 box seats.

The highlighted terms suggest the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is 11 choose 6. Using a calculator and the nCr function, 11 nCr 6 is 462 ways.